# Automatically loading more posts (checking if element is visible on screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function detects whether or not an element is visible on the screen. When a user scrolls to a "load" element I want to automatically request more posts to be displayed (AJAX). However, at the moment I have the following code:

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

  var scrolledCounter = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
    var scroll = isScrolledIntoView(".button.load-more");
    if(scroll==true){
      scrolledCounter++;
      loadMorePosts(scrolledCounter);
    }
  },500);
```

It works fine, but if the element is constantly in view (as it would be for slower-ish connections loading the information), it then loads more every 500ms. I'm wondering what method would be better than setInterval (?) to accomplish what I want to do.

i.e.

If the user scrolls to the load element, function `loadMorePosts` is called just once, then if it's not visible anymore, re-allow the function to be called again, such that if it's visible again the function is called once more again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(window).scroll()` method. It will occur every time users scrolls the page. 
I have added an `isScrolling` variable to prevent firing `loadMorePosts` more than once in a period.

```
var isScrolling = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = isScrolledIntoView(".button.load-more");
    if (scroll==true && !isScrolling)
    {
      isScrolling = true; // Block this function
      scrolledCounter++;
      loadMorePosts(scrolledCounter);
      setTimeout(function() { isScrolling = false; }, 500); // Unblock the function after 0.5s
    }
});
```

JSFiddle DEMO (without `isScrolling`): http://jsfiddle.net/0wbf9dn2/

Comment: `!isScrolling` stops `loadMorePosts` from ever firing